# Master-level Minicourse on Topological Properties of $SU(2)$ Sphalerons

Tags: differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, field-theory, group-theory, topology

I am doing a master's thesis on the properties and applications of $SU(2)$ sphalerons. I am in desperate need of a source (textbook, lecture notes, etc.) through which I can learn the basics of the relevant topology. I am aware of the numerous sources out there. I am looking for something concise, as time is an issue. Does such a source exist?